# layer list - margin bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list

I want to create an android layer list and I would to add my logo at the bottom of the screen. Now, I use this item :

```
<item android:bottom="40dp">
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logohw"
     android:gravity="bottom"/>
</item>
```

The logo is at the bottom of the screen but it's impossible to add a margin between the logo and the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to define all four elements because it is not margin from bottom it is padding of element.

```
<item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">

        <bitmap android:src="@android:drawable/logohw"/>

    </item>
```